# Redireccionar a página php en función del usuario logueado

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando en un sistema el cual consiste en un página principal de logins con php y mysql, en función del usuario logeado y almacenado en la session quiero que redirija a una u otra página, ya que cada usuario va a tener una página principal que no va a compartir similitudes con la de otro. Realizo el login de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$alert='';
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['active'])){
  header('location: datos/'.$_SESSION['user'].'.php');
}else{

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    if(empty($_POST['user'])||empty($_POST['password']))
    {
      $alert='Ingrese usuario y contraseña';
    }else{
      require_once "conexion.php";
      $user=$_POST['user']);
      $pass= $_POST['password']));


      $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND password='$pass'");
      $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
  
      if($result>0)
      {
          $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
          $_SESSION['active'] = true;
          $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
          $_SESSION['nombre'] = $data['nombre'];
          $_SESSION['correo'] = $data['correo'];
          $_SESSION['user'] = $data['user'];

          header('location: datos/'.$_SESSION['user'].'.php');

      }
      else{
        $alert = 'El usuario o la clave son incorrectos';
        session_destroy();
      }
      
    }

}
```

El problema me viene al redireccionar a la página al archivo .php

```
header('location: datos/'.$_SESSION['user'].'.php');
```

Recibo el siguiente mensaje, y se puede ver que la URL está bien formada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Redireccionando a un archivo .html me funciona sin problema, pero necesito que el archivo sea .php, ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar correctamente a este archivo con el nombre del usuario y extensión .php y comprobar si hay una sesion activa para, en el caso de que la haya redirigir al usuario a su portal en .php?

Este es el archivo al que redirecciono. Gracias

```
<?php

if(empty($_SESSION['active'])){
      header('location: ../index.php');
    }
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php include "scripts.php"; ?>
    <title>Alvaro page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HELLO ALVARO!</h1>
<button onclick="location.href='salir.php'">SALIR</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Te aseguraste que el nombre del archivo al cuál quieres acceder esté bien escrito (minúsculas y mayúsculas)?

Comment: Si, el nombre es el nombre de usuario.php, si lo pruebo con datos/'.$user.'.html' si que funciona

Comment: Lo que realmente debería estar pasando es una de dos cosas, 1- el archivo que intenta acceder el programa no se encuentra o tiene un nombre distinto. 2- El archivo está en una ubicación diferente a la que se específica. Asegúrate que el nombre no llegue con espacios u otro tipo de carácter no deseado.

Comment: Ahora bien, la URL que te da ese Error 403. ¿Ya la evaluaste? ¿Está bien formada? Si nada de eso comprueba ser el error. Será que tu archivo carece de privilegios de ejecución. Otra cosa sería evaluar si necesitas usar rutas relativas. ?¿Podrías agregar la estructura de directorios de tu proyecto?

Comment: descubrí el problema, viene en que al inicio de el archivo php cuando compruebo si la sesion esta vacía la variable $user no está definida, pero si evaluo con header('location: datos/'.$_SESSION['user'].'.php'); me da un error de demasiadas redirecciones. Actualizo la pregunta

Comment: en ves de ejecutar esto: `header('location: datos/'.$_SESSION['user'].'.php');` utiliza `echo 'location: datos/'.$_SESSION['user'].'.php';` y verifica que te sale por pantalla.

Comment: luego utiliza lo que te salio por pantalla en la url del navegador manualmente si te sigue saliendo el error es que tienes redundancia ...

Comment: La url está bien formada, pero me sigue saliendo el error, ¿a qué te refieres con lo de redundancia? ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes `session_start();` en la página del usuario?

Comment: No lo tenía, ese era mi problema, muchas gracias!.